# On Click Add Listener not working on Game Object

Tags: unity, gameobject

I have this code attached to a 3D cylinder game object. I plan to use it as an arrow and rotate it when clicked and dragged. I had no idea what do as I am a beginner so I started with adding an onClick listener to a Button component on the Cylinder, and wrote this script which I added as component to the cylinder.. But the Rotate() function isn't called when I click on it, as there is no message in the Log.. This is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MoveAim : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isAiming;
    private Button button;


    void Start () {
        isAiming = true;
        button = GetComponent <Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener (Rotate);
        Debug.Log ("Start!");
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
    }
    void Rotate() {
        Debug.Log ("Click recorded");
    }

}
```

Any idea what to do? And how should I implement the rotation of the cylinder? Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a button, which is an UI element. It is not supposed to be used on 3d objects in the game world.

On 3d objects in game world you probably want to use [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html). They work like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Clickable : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
  public void OnPointerClick( PointerEventData eventData )
  {
    Debug.Log ("Click recorded");
  }
}
```

Also note that the object should have a collider attached to it, and the scene must have [EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) and [Standalone Input Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-StandaloneInputModule.html) attached to some object.

There are [more events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SupportedEvents.html) supported to allow different behaviours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just realised that I could use void OnMouseDown() on the object. However, is that not recommended?

Comment: You can use whatever suits your needs. Using EventSystem is usually more flexible and it lets you do more things.